# How to mock a sequence of calls to the same method to return different values in AutoFixture using NSubstitute?

Tags: c#, autofixture, nsubstitute

I'm looking for a way to mock a method so that when called multiple times, the result is different. More specifically what i'm after, is to mock a method so that the third time it is called, I want to assert against that result.

This syntax is *not* correct, but simulates what I want to accomplish:

```
var foo = Fixture.Freeze<IFoo>();
foo.Exists(Arg.Any<object>()).Returns("firstcall").SecondCall("secondcall").ThirdCall("thirdcall");
```

Can you do this in AutoFixture?

EDIT: As pointed out by Mark this is a question related to NSubstitute rather than AutoFixture itself. I've updated the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out the answer before submitting the question, so I'll post the answer here:

```
Fixture.Freeze<IFoo>()
    .Exists(Arg.Any<object>())
    .Returns("default", "firstcall", "secondcall", "thirdcall");
```

Now when `Exists()` is called three times, the response will be `"firstcall"` then `"secondcall"` then `"thirdcall"`. Any call after this will receive `"default"`.

Comment: AFAICT, this is a feature of the underlying dynamic mock library you're using (NSubstitute?), and has little to do with AutoFixture.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Ah yes that is true, thanks. Will update the answer.